# Get Menu Values from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

All,
I'm using the following code to get all of the defined wordpress menus that are created:

```
$menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
```

I know the ID of the menu I want to use. Based on the menu ID I'd like to get the Pages that are in that menu and the corresponding Navigation Label based on a selected menu ID. How can I go about doing that?

I actually discovered this:

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($options['menu_choice']);
```

In that example the $options['menu_choice'] is the selected Menu ID but what I really would like is to give the permalink value. Can I get that from this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Did you know there's a StackExchange site dedicated to Wordpress? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37959604/1153703

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the title and url of each item in a menu using the `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` function:

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $options['menu_choice'] );
foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
    $title = $menu_item->title;
    $url = $menu_item->url;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

That's exactly what you want.

```
$menu_name = 'menu-id'; //e.g. primary-menu; $options['menu_choice'] in your case

if (($locations = get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations[$menu_name])) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($locations[$menu_name]);
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
}
```

Now $menu_items is an object that contains all data for all menu items. So you can retrieve necessary data using `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($menu_items as $menu_item) {
    $id = $menu_item->ID;
    $title = $menu_item->title;
    $url = $menu_item->url;

    if ($parent_id = $menu_item->menu_item_parent) {
        //the element has a parent with id $parent_id, so you can build a hierarchically menu tree
    }
    else {
        //the element doesn't have a parent
    }
}
```

You can find more interesting information for this question, such as orderby options, on official website: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Answer (score 2):

You want to display a specific menu? why not use a simpler function, `wp_nav_menu`, and pass an argument of your desirable menu-ID? just replace your menu_id with $menu_ID in the next example:

```
<?php 
$menu_args = array('menu' => $menu_ID );
wp_nav_menu( $menu_args ); 
?>
```

Comment: $menu_ID = '195'; 
$menu_args = array('menu' => $menu_ID );
wp_nav_menu( $menu_args );

Answer (score 1):

To get the post ID then you will have to pull it using this function :

$id = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );

Otherwise the id will be the nav_menu custom type post that wordpress uses for the menus.
Same goese for the $url, you can call it using get_permalink($id);

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre> 
$menu_ID = '195'; // 195 is a menu id this id you can see 
http://example.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=195
$menu_args = array('menu' => $menu_ID );
wp_nav_menu( $menu_args );  
</pre>
```