# menu item in array

Tags: wordpress, menu

How do I get the menu items (depth = 1) into an array?

wp_nav_menu outputs a formatted list with both ul and li elements.
wp_list_pages also outputs a formatted list with both ul and li.

I just want to get the menu items (striped of tags) of depth one into an array.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I think this will helps you: [**wp get nav menu items**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items)

```
    $menu_name = 'custom_menu_slug'; // Get the nav menu based on $menu_name (same as 'theme_location' or 'menu' arg to wp_nav_menu)

    if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);


    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
        $title = $menu_item->title;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. $menu_name will be the same as what the menu is called under the option "Appearance > Menus: Menu Name (for the menu I want to use)?

Comment: No. [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642278/wordpress-list-menu-items-without-links-as-plain-text-without-links/11642603#11642603)

Comment: Works for me, without the location check.

Comment: Works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Libin

Figured out wp_get_nav_menu_items()

```
$menu_name = 'sidebar-menu'; //menu slug
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
$menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($menuitems);
echo "</pre>";
```

here i am getting the whole menu items

I fount one example here http://wiki.workassis.com/wordpress-get-menu-array/